# Difficulty with saving and retrieving dictionaries with user defined names

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, storage

I want to make a program (It's for Pokemon Tabletop United if you need context) where I can enter values into a dictionary template and then save it with a user-inputted name into one file where I can then retrieve that data for later use. I've done a lot of research and I'm still not sure what the best way to do this is. I'm pretty much a beginner so I apologize if my language isn't great. Here's what I have for code so far:

---

```
command = input('What would you like to do?  ')

move = {
    'name' : '',
    'type' : 0,
    'ac' : 0,
    'basedamage' : [0, 0, 0],
    'class' : 0,
    'range' : [0, 0],
    'effect' : '',
}

movecache = {}
#entering in the values for a move and storing it in "movecache"

if command == ('newmove'):
    movecache = move.copy()
    movecache['name'] = input('What is the name of the move?  ')
    movecache['type'] = input('what is the move type?  ')
    movecache['ac'] = input('AC?  ')
    movecache['basedamage'][0] = input('how many dice?  ')
    movecache['basedamage'][1] = input('how many sides on the dice?  ')
    movecache['basedamage'][2] = input('What is the consant?  ')
    movecache['class'] = input('class?  ')
    movecache['range'][0] = input('range?  ')
    movecache['effect'] = input('effect?  ')
    print(movecache)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What's the problem? You didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a **list of dictionaries** or perhaps a more complicated structure.  for example, you can add username as another key to your dictionary and then you can take input to the dictionary as you are doing then append it to a list.

Once you have your data you can write it to file (probably json format).